# Spring-Mongo : mapping mongo document field/s to BasicDBObject/Map of BasicDBObject of an Entity

Tags: spring, mongodb, mapping

I have an entity `ProjectCycle` mapped to mongo DB collection `ProjectCycle`. I am trying to retrieve 2 fields, `_id` and `Status`. I am able to retrieve both like the following

```
@Document(collection="ProjectCycle")
public class ProjectCycle {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("Status")
    private String status;
//getters and setters
}
```

> 

```
Application.java

    Query query = new Query();
    query.fields().include("Status");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.and("_id").is("1000");
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    Iterable<ProjectCycle> objectList = mongoOperations.find(query, ProjectCycle.class);
    for(ProjectCycle obj : objectList) {
        System.out.println("_id "+obj.getId());
        System.out.println("status "+obj.getStatus());
    }
```

> Output

```
_id 1000
status Approved
```

But, the problem is when i use an Entity with field `private DBObject basicDbObject;` instead of `private String status;` i am getting value as `null` instead of `Approved`

I have tried like the following

```
public class ProjectCycle {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private DBObject basicDbObject;
    //getter & setter
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that, the collection '`ProjectCycle`' is very large and creating a POJO corresponding to it is quiet difficult. Also I am only reading data from mongoDB. So creating the entire POJO is time wasting and tedious.

- How I can achieve mapping between any field/fields from mongo Collection to entity?.
- Will it be possible to create a `Map<String, BasicDBObject> objectMap;` to fields returned from query? I am using `Spring-data-mongodb` for the same.

> Version details
>
> Spring 4.0.7.RELEASE
>
> spring-data-mongodb 1.7.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping your query like below.

```
Iterable<BasicDBObject> objectList = mongoOperations.find(query, BasicDBObject.class, collectionname);

for(BasicDBObject obj : objectList) {
    System.out.println("_id "+obj.get("id"));
    System.out.println("status "+obj.get("status"));
}
```